# Accessing [object Object] from MySQL in javascript react

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

In the below Picture I am getting [object Object] from my index.js express backend when `'/api/getUsername'` is called it should return the number 33 from a column called `age` in MySQL database that has a value of 33 int.

I return this in the front end via `res.send({ username: result }); however, I am unable to get to the value of the [object Object] and display the 33 value that it contains.

[image]

index.js

```
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});


const app = express();


app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE age = ?', 33, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send({ username: result });
  });
});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './app.css';
import ReactImage from './react.png';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { username: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/getUsername')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(user => this.setState({ username: user.username }));
  }

  render() {
    const { username } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {username ? <h1>{`Hello ${ username}`}</h1> : <h1>Loading.. please wait!</h1>}
        <img src={ReactImage} alt="react" />
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any more info I can add.

Thank you
Carl

Comment: Log the `user` response on the front end before setting it in state and see what it actually is

Comment: @Jayce444 I just logged it below is the result 

Array (1)
0 {AGE: 33}

Array Prototype

Comment: @Jayce444 
So this means the AGE: 33 value is getting to the user but for some reason it's not displaying?

Comment: Print `username` in render to see what is inside the object: `console.log(JSON.stringify(username))`

Comment: @palindrom
I put what you told me after render() { and just before return and got two things in the console 1 null and 2 [{"AGE":33}]

Comment: Print`result` to see the result of the sql query and set `username` accordingly. The select query returns an array of rows. And each row is also an array. You need to limit query to return one row and set username to the related column of the table , maybe like `result[0].username`.

Comment: @palindrom you were abousutly right about the JSON.stringify(username) I put it between render and return. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @palindrom do you know if its possable to interact with the json within the render function I attempted username[0]["AGE"] but it wouldn't have it.

Comment: @palindrom all working now I was doing it in the wrong place just did it in the index.js thanks, res.send({ username: result[0]['AGE'] });

Comment: @palindrom I cannot find how to accept your answer via comments, what should I do?

Comment: Glad that I helped. You cannot accept comments. You can answer your own question if you like.